# Why is the rate widget (from the Rate module) not showing up?

Tags: entities, views, rating

I'm using the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module, together with the entity reference module.

I have a content type let's name it "Gallery". I also created a "Photo" content type, then added a "yes/no" rate widget  to this content type.[image: screen shot] (c)

In "Gallery" I have an entity reference to "Photo".

Now I'm going to make a View like this: Show all of "Photo"s related to this "Gallery" plus rate widget related to every "Photo".

I created a view with nid as argument to get specific node, and two relation, first one is "Entity Reference: Referenced Entity", and second one is "Vote result". then I added first relation as a relation to second relation.[image: screen shot]

I added "Vote results:value" as field. So far I see the "Photos", but I couldn't get the rate widgets.

What am I missing to also get the rate widgets to show up?

Comment: sorry, I edited my qustion.

Comment: OK, "much" better, but still it does not contain even 1 question "mark" ... To avoid we have to guess what the real question is, please EDIT your question one more time to include an actual question. Probably something like "What am I missing to also get the rate widgets to show up?" Note: I slightly edited your question also, Mostly by replacing br-tags by a line feed (with the same formatting result). Just trying to help, ok?

Comment: OK, "now" we have a real question ... which is no longer on hold either ... and a +1 one from me already. Fingers crossed now for an "answer"! Note: consider checkout out the 'tour' within the help pages also (your profile shows you've not visited that yet) ...

Comment: actually I've visited tour page before logged in, thank You anyway :)

Comment: And by visiting it again a few mins ago you earned the "informed" badge ... That's at leat what your profile tells me now ...!

Comment: Consider further editing your question with (a) How did you actually implement that '... yes/no" rate widget ...' and (b) some details about the actual "rate" module you're using (there are multiple modules (the tag you used suggests it is the 'rate' module and (c) adding a screenprint with the view you created so far (screenprint using the Views UI).

Answer (score 0):

From the screenprint about "**edit widget**" in your question it shows that you've created a "Yes / no" widget using the [Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) module.

But nowhere in your question it shows for which "***Node types***" you've enabled your widget. Since you're using the "Yes / no" widget (located at `admin/structure/rate/add?template=yesno` when adding a new widget), you should indicate the desired "Node types" there for which the rating widget is to be enabled. If you didn't specify (select) any of node type, then that would explain ***why the rate widget is not showing up***".